# Boolean not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

For some reason the boolean difference won't work. I'm trying to use the "123" to carve holes into the "Cube.622"

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3n3p2swgzq2z7g/Church.blend?dl=0

link to the file

Comment: it looks like it works, the problem is that the faces of 123 barely touch the faces of Cube622, besides that Cube622 is not a closed shape, it has a lot of holes, so it's not considered like "full"